# How to check for overlapping check with tolerance using JTS / GeoTools

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite

I have several hundered polygons which may overlap but need to be considered 'not overlapping' when the overlapping is less than 1 meter.
The overlapping check in JTS does not offer a tolerance parameter. I'm looking for a pattern how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by making a [negative buffer](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#buffer%28double%29) (0.5m) for each geometry before testing the overlap.

E.g. you have this two overlaping polygons, 1m overlap:
[image]

By making a negative buffer (-0.5m) of the blue polygon you'll get the yellow one:
[image]

And this are the two buffered polygons:
[image]

Running the binary predicate test in JTS test builder, you'll get no overlap:

[image]